# Angular / Kendo Grid: "HTML Helper" Equivalent / Sub-Template for Grid Columns?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-components

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent to Razor Helper / ASP.NET MVC HTML Helpers in Angular.

The scenario: I have chunks of HTML that I want to be able to store in a single place, so I can put them within the same component multiple times without having to copy/paste the code a lot.

Why Components won't work: The sections of HTML I want to chunk out, are within a larger component's HTML. And that component expects only specific child components to exist. In this case, it is [Kendo Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/).

In a typical Kendo Grid for Angular, the HTML looks something like this:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

In my scenario, I have a collection of `kendo-grid-column` that are essentially repeated. It would be great if I could section them off to their own piece, that I could invoke multiple times:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
    <app-some-complicated-set-of-columns [data]="childCollection1"></app-some-complicated-set-of-columns>
    <app-some-complicated-set-of-columns [data]="childCollection2"></app-some-complicated-set-of-columns>
    <app-some-complicated-set-of-columns [data]="childCollection3"></app-some-complicated-set-of-columns>
</kendo-grid>
```

Unfortunately, Kendo does not render the columns within that component. I attempted to do the same within a `<kendo-grid-column-group>` element, but if you try that, it throws an error instead of simply not rendering them. Something to the effect of "you can only put `<kendo-grid-column>` component instances inside `<kendo-grid-column-group>`."

**While there probably isn't a way around either of these, I would love to hear if there are any ways in Angular to essentially say "replace this with a section of HTML directly, as if it were written inline."** Solutions to either the specific Kendo problem, or the more generic Angular problem, are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question right , but to replace  a section of HTML directly you write it with  and in the content child of the parent component you play with ngTempateOutlet and/ or ngTemplateOutletContext

For Kendo it seems they are supporting it with this :-
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CellTemplateDirective/

You could try creating separate components for the repeated logic and give it inside the ng-template to avoid repeated code

Comment: This is good stuff! But it appears to be slightly different than what I'm going for.

I'm looking to take several `<kendo-grid-column>` instances, and wrap them up in some thing that I can call repeatedly. As opposed to just defining a template within a single cell. Also looks like Kendo ignores `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet=...>` inserts as well, unfortunately...

Comment: Wrapping several kendo-grid-column in a component and calling them repeatedly might not be possible. The kendo-grid component could be only expecting contentchildren of type kendo-grid-column , writing your own custom grid will be the only solution i can think of in that case. With the second comment , I migth be able to answer better if I see the code